# Textract in R (paws) without S3Object

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, pdf, r-paws

When using `textract` from the `paws` package in R the `start_document_analysis` call requires the path to a S3Object in `DocumentLocation`.

```
textract$start_document_analysis(
    DocumentLocation = list(
      S3Object = list(Bucket = bucket, Name = file)
    )
  )
```

Is it possible to use `DocumentLocation` without a S3Object? I would prefer to just provide the path to a local PDF.

Answer (score 2):

The start_document_analysis api only supports providing an s3 object as input, and not a base64 encoded string like the analyze_document api (see also CLI docs on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/textract/start-document-analysis.html)

So unfortunately you have to use S3 as a place to (temporarily) store your data. Of course you can write your own logic to do that :). Great tutorial on that can be found at
https://www.gormanalysis.com/blog/connecting-to-aws-s3-with-r/
Since you have already set up credentials etc. you can skip a lot of the steps and start at step 3 for example.

Answer (score 1):

`paws` also has support for the sync functions: https://www.paws-r-sdk.com/docs/textract/

e.g. https://www.paws-r-sdk.com/docs/textract_detect_document_text/, but be careful, as the example isn't always perfect. In this case, they say it accepts an argument:
`Document [required] The input document as base64-encoded bytes or an Amazon S3 object.` along with the example:

```
svc$detect_document_text(
  Document = list(
    Bytes = raw,
    S3Object = list(
      Bucket = "string",
      Name = "string",
      Version = "string"
    )
  )
)
```

However, feeding a base64 string to `Bytes` will throw an error:

```
# Error: `In file(what, "rb") : cannot open file ...`
result = textract$detect_document_text(
  Document = list(Bytes = knitr::image_uri('image.png')))
```

Instead, you can provide the file path:

```
result = textract$detect_document_text(Document = list(Bytes='image.png'))
```

In your case, try using [`analyze_document`](https://www.paws-r-sdk.com/docs/textract_analyze_document/).